# MySQL : Different behaviors depending on WHERE result

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I'm modifying an existing project. I want to group 3 mysql request in one.

These 3 request have the same selected data, only the WHERE change.
here's one of the request for exemple :

```
SELECT COUNT(seg.my_seg1) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cp.conference_id) as my_seg1 FROM A.Account a
INNER JOIN A.ConferenceParticipant cp ON a.account_id = cp.user_id
INNER JOIN A.Conference cf ON cf.id = cp.conference_id
WHERE cf.`status` = 0
AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= cf.creation_timestamp
GROUP BY a.account_id) as seg
WHERE seg.my_seg1 >= 30
```

The 2 other requests are exactly the same except :

```
WHERE seg.my_seg1 >= 11 AND seg.my_seg1 <= 30;
```

and :

```
WHERE seg.my_seg1 >= 30;
```

So my question is how can I get 3 different values depending on the WHERE result in the same request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this you'll have 3 virtual columns:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(IF(seg.my_seg1 >= 30, 1, 0)) AS res1,
    COUNT(IF(seg.my_seg1 >= 11 AND seg.my_seg1 < 30, 1, 0)) AS res2
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cp.conference_id) as my_seg1 
    FROM A.Account a
            JOIN A.ConferenceParticipant cp ON a.account_id = cp.user_id
            JOIN A.Conference cf ON cf.id = cp.conference_id
    WHERE 
        cf.`status` = 0
    AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= cf.creation_timestamp
    GROUP BY a.account_id
) AS seg
```

But you have to revise your filters, you talk about 3 but I only see 2 different ones.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed thanks a lot. There is only 2 indeed, copy/paste fail.
Haven't tried it yet but seems perfect.

Comment: ok, I edited then. Also, I changed the upper bound to be `< 30`, instead of  `<= 30`, otherwise you would count twice the `= 30` results. Not sure if that's you want...

Comment: It's the idea. Thanks again.